# Custom ListView onClick change Image, notifyDataSetInvalidated not working after restart activity

Tags: android, android-listview, wear-os

I'm creating a listview that contains an image and text. notifyDataSetInvalidated() works when I started the activity for the 1st time, the image did change after onclick. However, when I restart the activity, the notifyDataSetInvalidated() is not working and the image doesn't change. These are the codes that I wrote.

listview.activity

```
@Override
public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
     listView = (ListView)stub.findViewById(R.id.setting_item_listview);
     launcherSwitch = (Switch) stub.findViewById(R.id.Launcher_switch);

     adapter = new CustomListItem(WOMSettingActivity.this,
                    WOMSettingActivity.this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.setting_item),imageId,app);
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
               imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_black);
               for(int i = 0; i < imageId.length;i++){
                    if(position == i){
                         checkState[i] = true;
                    }else{
                         checkState[i] = false;
                    }
               }
               adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
          }
     });
}
```

CustomListItem

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
     final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingtextlayout,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_text);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(launcherPosition[position]);
    if(checkstate[position]){
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_black);
    }else{
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Please show me where did I did wrongly.
thank you

Comment: how you restarted the activity? is it by pressing back button and relaunching or just minimizing the activity and coming back?

Comment: can you please give me the declaration of checkState and imageId

Comment: @EldhoseMBabu Currently doing on Android-Wear, just swipe from left to right to quit the activity. I had checked on the Log for onDestroy() in listview.activity. After that, i relaunch the activity, the notifyDataSetInvalidated() is not working

Comment: @EldhoseMBabu
checkState is a boolean array - I use it to store which item had been checked, the item will be checked when the activity is started.

ImageId is the Integer array to store the drawable file for the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created another class and did some correction.

listview.activity

```
 public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            listView = (ListView)stub.findViewById(R.id.setting_item_listview);
            launcherSwitch = (Switch) stub.findViewById(R.id.Launcher_switch);

            adapter = new CustomListItem(WOMSettingActivity.this,list,app);
            Log.d(TAG,"adapter : " + adapter.getCount());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    for(int i = 0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                    if(position == i){ 
                      adapter.getItem(position).setChecked(true);
                     }else{
                      adapter.getItem(position).setChecked(false);
                     }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
```

class

```
public class setting(){
  private String Position;
  private boolean checked;

  public setting(String Position, boolean checked){
    this.Position = Position;
    this.checked = checked;
}
// Getter and setter
}
```

list class extend setting

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
     final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingtextlayout,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_item_text);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtTitle.setText(getItem(position).getPosition());
    if(getItem(position).isChecked()){
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_red);
    }else{
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_black);
    }
 return convertView;
}
```

notifyDataSetChanged() is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
notifyDataSetChanged();    //Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
```

instead of

```
notifyDataSetInvalidated();    //Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data is no longer valid or available.
```

Refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: Changed to notifyDataSetChanged() but the problem still exist.

Comment: can you please make sure the onItemClick method is getting called after the activity is restarted.

Comment: Yes, I had inserted a Log just before the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); the onItemClick method did get call everytime I press

Comment: what about imageId? what it contains and from where you are populating it?

Comment: This is the ImageId
private Integer[] imageId={
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };
I'm populating it from the listview.activity